# Mule Collection aggregator

Tags: esb, mule

I am trying to use Mule 3.2.0 s Collection Aggregator. I tried using Mule Studio but seems it is still not available in Mule studio for configuration though the icon does appear in the "Flow Control" section.
My use case is -
I get a message from a VM Inbound endpoint. I now want to pass that to 3 different flows - all using the same request object but performing different operations - say A,B,C. All of them update their respective databases but they are all part of a common Order_ID(somethig internal to our application). The 3 processes may take different processing times but once done each of them return the same success response. I want to use an aggregator which will aggregate all these responses without timing out and then forward that to a Java component or another VM Endpoint for further processing.
The Mule documentation for Collection Aggregator doesn't seem to be very informative so if some one who has used Collection Agg can help me out with the xml config for the above scenario it will be very helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Collection Aggregator` use `All` message processor. It sends the same message to every processor inside it and aggregates the results after they finish.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-All

Sample config: (I send "foo" to the vm endpoint)

```
<flow name="main" processingStrategy="asynchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in"/>
    <all>
        <flow-ref name="flow1"/>
        <flow-ref name="flow2"/>
    </all>

    <logger message="#[payload:]" level="INFO"/>
</flow>

<flow name="flow1">
    <append-string-transformer message="bar1"/>
</flow>

<flow name="flow2">
    <append-string-transformer message="bar2"/>
</flow>
```

Console output:

```
INFO  2012-08-15 17:26:01,749 [main.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [foobar1, foobar2]
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I guess you are referring to this bit in the link above    - "All messages (if any) returned by the targets are aggregated together and form the response from this processor."    However this didn;t really work this way  with ALL. I am actually using ALL at the moment and it simply forwards the message to all of them and they die out at the end of their respective flows. If I add another Java component after the ALL it gets invoked as soon as messages have been delivered to the 3 ALL targets and doesn;t really wait for response from the 3. DO you have an sample config? Thanks

Comment: This is probably because the way you invoke the A, B and C flows from ALL is asynchronous (ie. `one-way`).

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample config, it works fine. Can you provide more details of your flows config?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Got a bit side-tracked with some work. I will try this in a day and get back and update. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would go with  to use ALL component and the endpoint you use should be request-response (two-way where the flow waits for the response).

Thus the ALL component will aggregate the response an then returns you a CopyOnWriteArrayList with all the response from the flows A,B and C. This Array list you can transform in any desired way using a custom transformer by extending AbstractTransformer in your java class.

Cheers,
Naveen Raj